# Using recursion, getting max int out of a string of numbers and letters?

Tags: java, string, recursion

My class is on Chapter 18 of the Intro to Java book, which is the chapter about Recursion. So this is what it says:

"For this assignment, you will write two recursive functions, both of which will parse any length string that consists of digits and numbers.  Both functions should be in the same class and have the following signatures."

Now the first one was int sumIt(String s) to sum the ints in a given string. I completed this part, and you just have to look at each char and see if it is a number and then add it to the total if so. Then in the return, recall the function with that char removed.

The second function is int findMax(String s, int max). So basically the way I think it will work is that you start with max 0 and then you call the function again in the return, and each time check if the next int is bigger than the max, and replace if so. I originally wrote this very similar to the first function(check my code), but then I realized, in this one, you cannot go character by character. If the string is "xg12zz128-p/9" the max should be 128. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to get the next integer in the string. I'm not sure what to do.

Here is my code:

```
public class Finder {


    public int sumIt(String s) {

        int total = 0;

        if(s.length() > 0) {  // checks that the string still has characters
            if(s.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]")) {   // checks if the first character is a number
                total += Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 1)); // if num, parses into integer and adds it total
                return total + sumIt(s.substring(1)); // return total and use recursursion to continue searching the string for ints
            }
            else {
                return total + sumIt(s.substring(1));  // needed this else clause in case the char was not a number
            }
        }
        else {
            return total; // return total when there are no more characters
        }
    }

    public int findMax(String s, int max) {

        if (s.length() > 0) { // checks for characters

            if(s.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]")) { // checks for number

                int a = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 1));     // parse num to int    

                if(a > max) {
                    return findMax(s.substring(1), a);  // if the new int is bigger, we call the function again with that set as max
                }
                else return findMax(s.substring(1), max); // else we just use the old max
            }
            else return findMax(s.substring(1), max); // in case its not a num
        } 
        else return max; // return max when all characters are gone.
    }

}
```

and then here is the JUnit test file that is being used. Probably don't need to see this code but at least then you can see examples of the answers.

```
package week4.Whitelaw;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestRecursion
{

    @Test
    public void testSumIt()
    {
        Finder finder = new Finder();

        assertEquals(6, finder.sumIt("1d2d3d") );
        assertEquals(10, finder.sumIt("55") );
        assertEquals(0, finder.sumIt("xx") );
        assertEquals(1, finder.sumIt("00001") );
        assertEquals(3, finder.sumIt("x0x0w1y2") );
        assertEquals(21, finder.sumIt("123456") );
        assertEquals(21, finder.sumIt("x123456x") );
        assertEquals(7, finder.sumIt("1ggggg60") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testMax()
    {
        Finder finder = new Finder();

        // assume max is the smallest possible number
        int max = 0;

        assertEquals(12, finder.findMax("12x8",max) );
        assertEquals(88, finder.findMax("012x88",max) );
        assertEquals(100, finder.findMax("012x88ttttt9xe33ppp100",max) );
        assertEquals(128, finder.findMax("128",max) );
        assertEquals(0, finder.findMax("abcdef",max) );
        assertEquals(123456, finder.findMax("123456",max) );
        assertEquals(2, finder.findMax("x2x1x",max) );
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to describe the problem you've encountered, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Comment: while the character at the index at is a digit, increment your index.  If it's not a digit, everything before it is a number.

Comment: It doesn’t seem we have to take a leading minus into account? In `"-29z4"` the max is 29, not 4?

Comment: Yeah sorry I shouldn't have put a minus

Answer (score 1):

Using pseudo code, since your question is focused on a logic rather than syntax, here's one possible solution,

```
findMax(string s, int currentMax, int currentInt)
    if s is empty
        return currentMax
    if s.firstChar() is not an int
        currentMax = max(currentMax, currentInt)
        return findMax(s.substring(1), currentMax, 0)
    int t = parseInt(s.firstChar())
    currentInt = currentInt * 10 + t
    return findMax(s.substring(1), currentMax, currentInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go character by character for sumit either. If you did that, you'd get a result of 4 for the string ab11cd11ed when the actual answer should be 22.

Comment: Well my point was that the first one doesn't seem to be that way. If you look at the junit test file, the answer for something like "123456" is 21. You just add each individual number up.

The second one is different.

Answer (score 0):

I see you’re already using a regular expression, so I thought there was a possibility you would be allowed to do more of that. If so, you can do something like:

```
    Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+");
    Matcher m = integerPattern.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        String integerAsString = m.group();
        // ...
    } else // ...
```

Now you can parse the integer and do a recursive call with the same number of characters removed from the input string as the length of `integerAsString`. I trust you to complete that yourself. `integerPattern` can be a static constant in your class, of course, if you like.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I've been working off of this. I get the first set of digits but after that it messes up. I'll keep messing around with it.

Comment: You are incredible. I'm not sure if this is the exact way  my teacher wanted me to do it, but after tinkering with it, it works. I don't know much about the patterns, but I know that the ^ means beginning of the line, so I had to get it to remove the first character if it was not a num and recall the function, and then that way if it got to a num it would be at the beginning.